# Add code before closing head of Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am new to magento.  I have some products in my magento 2 website. I want to add some custom meta code before closing of head tag.  Example

```
if (page_id==1){
 some code 
}
if(page_id==2){
other code 
}
```

So in which php page I have to add this code?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin Panel > Content > Configuration**, click "edit" next to your site, scroll down to the HTML Head section and add your code there under scripts and stylesheets.

Source with pictures: https://magefan.com/blog/magento2-adding-custom-code-in-head

Not to be that guy but this was literally the first result when copying and pasting your question title into google.

Comment: please understand the question ,  I have separate code for each pages . If i write something in the configuration HTML head it will effect all pages . That's why i write the if condition

Comment: ok, if that is the case please edit the question to add that or I can do it for you. It isn't clear from the question that you want to only have the code on specific product pages.

Comment: i got answer friend . https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286650/magento-2-add-custom-code-before-closing-head-tag